# App crashing on android 8 to 12 due to java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, crash, pushy

I kindly ask for help. My app is crashing on Android, from versions 8 to 12. I'm having an crash reports from googleplay. I have zero idea on how to deal with this. Help!

Here is the Stacktrace:

``
Type java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

```
Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging;
  at me.pushy.sdk.util.PushyFirebase.register (PushyFirebase.java:12)
  at me.pushy.sdk.Pushy.register (Pushy.java:213)
  at me.pushy.sdk.cordova.internal.PushyPlugin.register (PushyPlugin.java:245)
  at me.pushy.sdk.cordova.internal.PushyPlugin.access$000 (PushyPlugin.java:27)
  at me.pushy.sdk.cordova.internal.PushyPlugin$1.run (PushyPlugin.java:53)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:929)

Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging;
  at me.pushy.sdk.util.PushyFirebase.register (PushyFirebase.java:12)
  at me.pushy.sdk.Pushy.register (Pushy.java:213)
  at me.pushy.sdk.cordova.internal.PushyPlugin.register (PushyPlugin.java:245)
  at me.pushy.sdk.cordova.internal.PushyPlugin.access$000 (PushyPlugin.java:27)
  at me.pushy.sdk.cordova.internal.PushyPlugin$1.run (PushyPlugin.java:53)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:923)

Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging;
  at me.pushy.sdk.util.PushyFirebase.register (PushyFirebase.java:12)
  at me.pushy.sdk.Pushy.register (Pushy.java:213)
  at me.pushy.sdk.cordova.internal.PushyPlugin.register (PushyPlugin.java:245)
  at me.pushy.sdk.cordova.internal.PushyPlugin.access$000 (PushyPlugin.java:27)
  at me.pushy.sdk.cordova.internal.PushyPlugin$1.run (PushyPlugin.java:53)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:920)

Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging;
  at me.pushy.sdk.util.PushyFirebase.register (PushyFirebase.java:12)
  at me.pushy.sdk.Pushy.register (Pushy.java:213)
  at me.pushy.sdk.cordova.internal.PushyPlugin.register (PushyPlugin.java:245)
  at me.pushy.sdk.cordova.internal.PushyPlugin.access$000 (PushyPlugin.java:27)
  at me.pushy.sdk.cordova.internal.PushyPlugin$1.run (PushyPlugin.java:53)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)

Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging;
  at me.pushy.sdk.util.PushyFirebase.register (PushyFirebase.java:12)
  at me.pushy.sdk.Pushy.register (Pushy.java:213)
  at me.pushy.sdk.cordova.internal.PushyPlugin.register (PushyPlugin.java:245)
  at me.pushy.sdk.cordova.internal.PushyPlugin.access$000 (PushyPlugin.java:27)
  at me.pushy.sdk.cordova.internal.PushyPlugin$1.run (PushyPlugin.java:53)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)

Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging;
  at me.pushy.sdk.util.PushyFirebase.register (PushyFirebase.java:12)
  at me.pushy.sdk.Pushy.register (Pushy.java:213)
  at me.pushy.sdk.cordova.internal.PushyPlugin.register (PushyPlugin.java:245)
  at me.pushy.sdk.cordova.internal.PushyPlugin.access$000 (PushyPlugin.java:27)
  at me.pushy.sdk.cordova.internal.PushyPlugin$1.run (PushyPlugin.java:53)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processTask (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1187)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:784)
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)

Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging;
  at me.pushy.sdk.util.PushyFirebase.register (PushyFirebase.java:12)
  at me.pushy.sdk.Pushy.register (Pushy.java:213)
  at me.pushy.sdk.cordova.internal.PushyPlugin.register (PushyPlugin.java:245)
  at me.pushy.sdk.cordova.internal.PushyPlugin.access$000 (PushyPlugin.java:27)
  at me.pushy.sdk.cordova.internal.PushyPlugin$1.run (PushyPlugin.java:53)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:784)
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)

Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging;
  at me.pushy.sdk.util.PushyFirebase.register (PushyFirebase.java:12)
  at me.pushy.sdk.Pushy.register (Pushy.java:213)
  at me.pushy.sdk.cordova.internal.PushyPlugin.register (PushyPlugin.java:245)
  at me.pushy.sdk.cordova.internal.PushyPlugin.access$000 (PushyPlugin.java:27)
  at me.pushy.sdk.cordova.internal.PushyPlugin$1.run (PushyPlugin.java:53)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:919)

Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging;
  at me.pushy.sdk.util.PushyFirebase.register (PushyFirebase.java:12)
  at me.pushy.sdk.Pushy.register (Pushy.java:213)
  at me.pushy.sdk.cordova.internal.PushyPlugin.register (PushyPlugin.java:245)
  at me.pushy.sdk.cordova.internal.PushyPlugin.access$000 (PushyPlugin.java:27)
  at me.pushy.sdk.cordova.internal.PushyPlugin$1.run (PushyPlugin.java:53)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:784)
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)

Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging;
  at me.pushy.sdk.util.PushyFirebase.register (PushyFirebase.java:12)
  at me.pushy.sdk.Pushy.register (Pushy.java:213)
  at me.pushy.sdk.cordova.internal.PushyPlugin.register (PushyPlugin.java:245)
  at me.pushy.sdk.cordova.internal.PushyPlugin.access$000 (PushyPlugin.java:27)
  at me.pushy.sdk.cordova.internal.PushyPlugin$1.run (PushyPlugin.java:53)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1012)
```

``

I am currently researching on this online. I have got no helpful solution.

Here is the dependencies from my build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidxAppCompatVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-android')
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$androidxJunitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$androidxEspressoCoreVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'

    def appCenterSdkVersion = '4.3.1'
    implementation "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-analytics:${appCenterSdkVersion}"
}
```

Comment: Please share your added dependencies list in build.gradle  file, and update all firebase dependencies to their latest version.

Comment: I edited and added my build.gradle dependencies.

Comment: unable to see any firebase related dependency in your file

Comment: implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:27.1.0')

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'